# A class/interface with the same name already existed: SQLException and sqlException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, sqlexception

I had a code for a webservice which connects to a database running on MySQL. I had it cleaned and built, deployed successfully but when I tested the following error came out:

```
Invoking wsimport with http://localhost:8080/getExamInfo/getInfo?WSDL
Info:   parsing WSDL...
Info:   [ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.getexaminfo.SQLException" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
Info:   line 22 of http://localhost:8080/getExamInfo/getInfo?xsd=1
Info:   [ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "SqlException" is generated from here.
Info:   line 31 of http://localhost:8080/getExamInfo/getInfo?xsd=1
Info:   [ERROR] This error is caused because on Windows you cannot have both "SqlException.java" and "SQLException.java" in the same directory.
```

From my understandings, the problem is that NetBeans is trying to create multiple sqlexception.java in one folder with different case sensitivities. I tried a few solutions but nothing seems to work. How can I resolve this? I can show you the code if needed.

EDIT: This is what I've advanced so far. I created a new XML binding for the schema generated from the service, this time it didn't show any errors but can't deployed properly. I got this stack trace from glassfish:

```
Warning:   AS-DEPLOYMENT-00012
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.getExamInfo.getInfo
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:586)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:463)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> is trying to create multiple sqlexception.java in one folder with
>   different case sensitivities

According to error message, you use Windows and in the Windows OS impossible create two files with different case sensitivities in the same directory

> How can i resolve this?

It's may be resolved:

1. Change one of SqlException.java class,
2. if you use other OS than Windows,

If you cann't do this, give us wsdl files and your code.

Comment: Here is my code uploaded on github: [link](https://github.com/skydevourer/AIW-project/blob/master/getExamInfo.java). Another thing is the xsd schema which is generated by Netbeans: [link](https://github.com/skydevourer/AIW-project/blob/master/xsd). As I can see from the xsd file, line 18 and line 26 is the source of this conflict. Please take a look and give me an advice.